# Receiving KeyError - Screenshots included

Tags: python

I have a error that I am receiving after trying to extract a string from a CSV which is set up like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvkDZ.png)

This is the code

```
# read in api keys
df_api_keys = pd.read_csv(dir+'/api_keys.csv')
# extract api key
estated_api_key = df_api_keys.loc[df_api_keys['API']].iloc[0]
```

Please help. Here's the actual error as well [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUeQi.png)

Comment: what you want to achieve from this code? you want to get the first row value?

Comment: Please show a sample of the CSV (as text)

Comment: I need the first row value to be captured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get just the Key value:

```
df_api_keys["API"][0]
```

If by change you have many keys in the column, you can extract them like this:

```
list_API = []
for i in df_api_keys["API"]:
    list_API.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question it's unclear what the CSV looks like so let's assume it's like this:

```
,API
KEY,sDt8P6fTTAyQEwC5nOHGb6l5xO6U14
```

Then:

```
from pandas import read_csv

df = read_csv('api_keys.csv')
print(*df.API, sep='\n')
```

This allows for multiple rows in the CSV and will print all API keys.

**Output:**

```
sDt8P6fTTAyQEwC5nOHGb6l5xO6U14
```